# warning: [deprecation] getValue() in BluetoothGattCharacteristic has been deprecated in the code: byte[] countByte = characteristic.getValue();

Tags: java, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, mobile-development, bluetooth-gatt

I am updating my current code to API33, i got the warning- warning: [deprecation] getValue() in BluetoothGattCharacteristic has been deprecated
byte[] countByte = characteristic.getValue();

In the reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCharacteristic.html#getValue(), it says:
This method was deprecated in API level 33.
Use BluetoothGatt#readCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic) instead.

But there is no direct way to implement it on the code I have which is the:
byte[] countByte = characteristic.getValue();

How can I solve this?

Comment: Do you implement [`BluetoothGattCallback.onCharacteristicRead`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback#onCharacteristicRead(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt,%20android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic,%20byte[],%20int))?